# What is a good Telnet client implementation C#?

Tags: c#, .net, telnet

What would be a good open source Telnet client implementation in C#, which can be used in close code (i.e., not under GPL)?

Boaz

Answer (score 6):

Best C# Telnet Lib I've found is called Minimalistic Telnet.  Very easy to understand, use and modify.  It works great for the Cisco routers I need to configure.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/MinimalisticTelnet.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Boaz you should be able to come up with your own rather easily. All you need to do is create a console application, learn how parameters work, look for is a tutorial on how to use the TcpClient class and you're golden.

**EDIT:**

I understand now. I was thinking of the most basic type of telnet client. I don't think you'll be able to find free source code for a telnet client with vt100, vt52 and vtnt support.

Comment: Hi Ruport, that would be indeed be the way to go if I wanted to do my self. However, Telnet contains a handshaking protocol I rather avoid implementing if I have to.

Comment: Ah okay you should mention that you want it to include vt100, vt52, and vtnt support.